# Sending selected listview data to another forms textbox

Tags: c#, listview, textbox, sendmessage

Hello i have got one listview that has txt files names inside one folder in desktop. So as i right data there is delete update and add so when i select one item and right click i want that data name to fill name textbox when its opened so its like basicly if i pick 1.1.2 and select update delete for will open and fixx textbox1 as the selectd datas name

-i tried few things like public statci string but when i use it and run program listview shows empty like there is nothing inside

```
private void liste_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    #region listview fonksiyonları
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.Columns.Add("Versiyon No", 133, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Açıklama", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Tarih", 154, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    #endregion

    #region listviewde txt dosyalarını gösterme
    string[] dosyalar = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(masaustu + "\\Versiyonlar");
    string k = "";
    int deger = 0;
    foreach (var item in dosyalar)
    {
        ListViewItem lili = new ListViewItem();
        deger = item.LastIndexOf("\\");
        k = item.Remove(0, deger);
        k = k.Remove(0, 1);
        lili.Text = k;
        StreamReader oku = new StreamReader(masaustu + "\\" + "Versiyonlar" + "\\" + k);
        string OkunanVeri = oku.ReadToEnd();
        string[] dizi = OkunanVeri.Split(new string[] { ";", "$" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        lili.SubItems.Add(dizi[0]);
        lili.SubItems.Add(dizi[1]);
        listView1.Items.Add(lili);
    }

}
#endregion
#region txt içindekileri textboxda göstermek
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    liste frm = new liste();
    try
    {

        string a = "";
        a = "";
        a = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        StreamReader oku = new StreamReader(masaustu + "\\" + "Versiyonlar" + "\\" + a);
        string OkunanVeri = oku.ReadToEnd();
        string[] dizi = OkunanVeri.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var item in dizi)
        {
            textBox1.Text = OkunanVeri;
        }
        oku.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

this is the listview codes if its going to help you please help me i just started c#and i cant figure out how to do it

Comment: Tried debugging it? BTW you could simplify it with `lili.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item);` Check while debugging if you're getting valid values here. Also, is your issue that the listview is empty or that you can't populate the other form's textbox?

Comment: @AshwinNair i can get txts but i cannot send it to other form

Comment: You said "_listview shows empty like there is nothing inside_". What does that mean? If you want to access a textbox on another form, you'll have to use events/delegates or you'll get cross thread exceptions. You're setting it using `textBox1.Text = OkunanVeri;` implying the textbox is on the same form.

Comment: @AshwinNair thanks dude i sjut fixed the problem

Comment: Cool. What was the problem?

Comment: @AshwinNair i made this code and sent to other forms its kinda long codei cant send here but if thereis message ican send you if you want me to 
gonderilecekveri = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
                    string[] dizi1 = new string[1];
                    dizi1[0] = gonderilecekveri;
                    liste frm = new liste();

Answer (score -2):

i dont know what u looking for , this may help

in list view form:

```
private void openMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//contentmenu openbtn
    {

if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)//in listview form//on_click opnbtn   
{


string strSlctdtext=Convert.ToString(listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].SubItems[1].Text);
                TextBoxform objTextBoxform = new TextBoxform(strListSelectedtext);
                if (objTextBoxform.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //do somthing if u want some output from textboxform in return
                }
            }
        }
```

in textbox form

```
public TextBoxform(string strListviewselected)

{      
  InitializeComponent();

   textBox1.Text = strListviewselected;

  }
```